# JavaFXML create custom tag element that does not extend node

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, fxml

I would like to create a custom `tag`/`element` for my `fxml` file but I do not want this element to be forced to inherit from a `Pane`, `Button`, `TextField` and so on. Is there some interface that can be implemented in my custom element that would require me to implement lets say `fx()` method which is required to return a `Node`/`Region` element which is supposed to be rendered in the `Scene`. What I mean 
 if something like the following is possible?

```
public class CustomElement implements SOME_FXML_INTERFACE {

    private String myArg;

    public CustomElement(@NamedArg("myArg") myArg) {
        this.myArg = myArg;
    }

    // method that is required to be implemented by SOME_FXML_INTERFACE
    // this method retuns some GUI element which actually needs to be rendered in the Scene
    @Override
    public Object fx() {
        return new TextField(myArg);
    }

}


<HBox>
    <CustomElement myArg="some_argument"/>
</HBox>
```

All this so that I could have `CustomElement` who can accept custom argument in the contructor.

Comment: What do you want to return a node instead of extending Node?

Comment: I have changed `fx()` return type to `Object` since it would not compile the way it was written before. I do not want to extend Node because that would bring overhead properties/methods that Node has with it which I will not be using.

Comment: @SamOrozco There are many good reasons to prefer aggregation over inheritance. E.g. you might not want to commit to the type of `Node` you are returning (allowing to change from one node type to another in a later version, and being certain that no code will break); or you might want to return a different type of node depending on some condition. Subclassing a specific node would not allow you to do this; subclassing `Node` itself wouldn't let you, e.g., provide a `TextField`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create arbitrary objects, but factory objects can only be used by nodes that support this. (Technically you could do this but it would involve using a getter returning a new instance every time it's invoked.) However you can e.g. use your custom class as `cellFactory` for a `ListView`.

If you do not need to rely on an instance method, but are satisfied with a `static` factory method, you can use the `fx:factory` tag to specify a method to create the node instance and you do not need to implement any interface to do that:

```
package my.package;

...

public class CustomElement {

    public static Node fx() {
        return new TextField(myArg);
    }

}
```

```xml
<?import my.package.CustomElement?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <CustomElement fx:factory="fx" />
    </children>
</HBox>
```

More information is available in the [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements)

BTW: If your class has a `public` constructor not taking any parameters you can create an instance of that class simply by adding a element with the name of the class to the fxml. E.g. the following fxml results in an `ArrayList` when loaded; the ways you can use those instances is limited though;

```xml
<?import java.util.ArrayList?>

<ArrayList />
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as using a factory method, as [described by fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60676467/2189127), you can repurpose the builder mechanism to do this. As with `<fx:factory>`, which is limited to `static` methods with no arguments, the usage is a bit limited. However, here's an example factory/builder that creates either a `TextField` or a `Label`, depending on whether the `editable` flag is set:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.fxmlfactory;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.util.Builder;

public class Factory implements Builder<Node> {

    private String text = "" ;
    private boolean editable = false ;



    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }



    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }



    public boolean isEditable() {
        return editable;
    }



    public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
        this.editable = editable;
    }



    @Override
    public Node build() {
        if (editable) {
            return new TextField(text);
        } else {
            return new Label(text);
        }
    }


}
```

Here's an FXML file that uses this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox ?>
<?import javafx.scene.Node ?>


<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <center>
        <HBox spacing="5">
            <Node text="Hello" editable="false" />
            <Node text="Name" editable="true" />
        </HBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

To make the `FXMLLoader` aware of your builder, you have to specify a class to use it for. Here we can use it for `Node` (but this requirement is a bit restrictive, as you'll be essentially limited to a single builder). You do this by creating a `BuilderFactory` implementation:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.fxmlfactory;

import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.util.Builder;
import javafx.util.BuilderFactory;

public class NodeBuilderFactory implements BuilderFactory{

    private final JavaFXBuilderFactory defaultFactory = new JavaFXBuilderFactory();

    public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
        if (type == Node.class) {
            return new Factory();
        }
        return defaultFactory.getBuilder(type);
    }

}
```

and then registering it with the `FXMLLoader`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.fxmlfactory;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Example.fxml"));
        loader.setBuilderFactory(new NodeBuilderFactory());
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```